# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data'). at Login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am tyring to submit a user detail on login to the database, to allow the user access to the application. But after filling the form and clicking on login, I get an error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
at Login.jsx:65:1
at async login (Login.jsx:48:1).

However, I do not know too much about what the problem is specifically, where I made a mistake.
Below is my code for the login page:

```
const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!loginData.email && !loginData.password) {
      alert('All fields are required')
    } else if(!loginData.email) {
      alert('Email is required  ')
    } else if (!loginData.password) {
      alert('Password is required')

    } else {
      await Axios.post(`https://api.***.com/identity/v1/auth/login`, {...loginData}, 
      storage.getConfig())
      .then(async (res) => {

        if(res.data.error === false && res.data.status === 200) {
          storage.saveCredentials(res.data.token, res.data._id)
          userContext.setUsertype(res.data.data.userType)
          console.log(res.data);
        }

        if(res.data.error === false && res.data.status === 206) {
          if(res.data.errors[0] === 'email verification is requires') {
            alert('Email verification is required')
          }
        }

      }).catch((err) => {
        
        if(err.response.data.errors[0] === 'invalid credentials'){
          console.log('invalid credentials')

        } else {
          if(err.response.data.errors.length > 0){
            alert(err.response.data.errors[0])
          } else {
            alert(err.response.data.message)
          }
        }
      })
    }

  }
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: This error is occuring because you are trying to access data.error and data.status properties without making sure that .data exists. Check your axios response from the network to see what the server is returning to you and make sure to add optional chaining when needed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining